# How to get end user Machine name in IIS logs

Tags: c#, iis, logging, dns

IIS 7.0 and above. No load balancer involved in this setup. File being requested is a small spacer image which can be requested synchronously or aynchronous load using JQuery. The file is not important, It is just a way to get the end user to hit this IIS server for analytics.

I have a requirement to capture machine name of visitors from IIS logs. Current Log has client IP address already in there. Problem is IPs are short lived in our environment and if I don't resolve it to a machine name soon enough, it is not useful. So we need the machine name for visiting IP determined pretty much in real time.

What is a good approach to go about this. These are the options I found...

1) Enable reverse DNS lookup in IIS -> http://www.expta.com/2010/01/how-to-enable-reverse-dns-lookup-in-iis.html. This affects server performace and I am worried this will end up holding the user request and cause his page to load slow due to the increased expense of reverse lookup operation

2) Write a IIS log module that does enhances logging by doing a revere lookup of IPs and writing machine names in the log. >> I'm afraid this will slow the request turnaround time for end user and affect server performance due to the reverse DNS lookup. Pretty much I guess this is me doing point 1 above instead of relying to Microsoft's built in capability. At the end the realtime reverse DNS lookups will affect performance.

3) Same as point 1 or 2 above, but I will change the HTML of the page users are hitting to load the IIS hosted image file using a Async javascript call (as opposed to an inline call). That way end suer doesn't have to wait for this IIS request to complete and can haverest of the page (the content that matters to them) load without depending on the spacer image request to complete. But then browser will still dedicate one thread for the async image loading and it still is a performance hit for the end user.

4) Just use default IIS logging to log in real time. Have a separate C# app read the file every 5 minutes or so, detect the new lines added, parse them and get IP, do a reverse lookup and find machine name and log it to a database or flat file as requested. Flip side is that now I need to pretty much log in real time because if I don't log things immediately, the IP might have gotten assigned to a different machine by the time my application reads the log, finds it and does a reverse lookup on it. Also I have to deal with the complexity of reading the log file to read only newly inserted log entries after the previous read etc.

5) http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-real-time-logging -> I guess this is the same as point 2 above except it is written in VC++ instead of C#. So same disadvantages are there for this method also I guess

So every method out there seems to have downsides. What do you think is a good way to go around solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reversing IP to machine name is not possible due to the way routing works - many machines can come via the same IP.

If you found a way to map IP to machine name that is acceptable for you one approach could be to simply have site serving the image and doing all necessary discovery in normal request handler. This way you may also have more information about user (cookies, hauthentication headers, ...). This approach may be more flexible than configuring IIS logging.